# Debugging non-firing action in Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm having a tough time figuring out why this `action` isn't firing. I'm rendering a modal window, and in its template I have

```
<a {{action 'addImage'}}>Add an image</a>
```

which correctly throws an error, because nothing handles it. I want to handle it on the view, so I add

```
<a {{action 'addImage' target='view'}}>Add an image</a>
```

but now, nothing happens. No error, and if I add `addImage` to the view's `actions` hash, the handler doesn't get called.

I'm not sure why this is happening or how to debug. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My action was within a component, and so `view` in this case referred to that component, rather than the modal's view.

:facepalm: